# How to access list of json-like objects from web api?

Tags: python, json, urllib

Just a side project I'm doing right now playing around with covid19 api. And I was hoping for something that would let me access the data with something like `data2.countries`.

```
import requests as r
import urllib
import json

url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/south-africa'
foo = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(foo.read().decode())
data2 = json.parse(data)
print(data2)
```

The data looks like this - it's all in one list:

```
[{'Country': 'South Africa', 'CountryCode': '', 'Province': '', 'City': '', 'CityCode': '', 'Lat': '0', 'Lon': '0', 'Confirmed': 607045, 'Deaths': 12987, 'Recovered': 504127, 'Active': 89931, 'Date': '2020-08-22T00:00:00Z'},
 {'Country': 'South Africa', 'CountryCode': '', 'Province': '', 'City': '', 'CityCode': '', 'Lat': '0', 'Lon': '0', 'Confirmed': 609773, 'Deaths': 13059, 'Recovered': 506470, 'Active': 90244, 'Date': '2020-08-23T00:00:00Z'}]
```

So far I'm getting:

```
  File "~/20200813file/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    data2 = json.parse(data)

AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'parse'
```

Comment: remove the `data2` line . whatever you have created as `data` is correct, and you can just do `print(data.country)` and check

Comment: I did ```data = json.loads(foo.read().decode()) 

print(data.Country[0])``` and it gave AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Country'

Comment: try `data[0].Country`

Comment: `data` is a `list of dicts`. thats the reason you get `list object has no country attrib` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try converting it into a pandas Dataframe.

```
import urllib
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/south-africa'


foo = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(foo.read().decode())

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.Country)
```

Comment: Hey buddy, I decided to go with pandas thanks, This is pretty neat.

Comment: Mention not. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json.dumps`:

```
import requests as r
import urllib
import json

url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/south-africa'

foo = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(foo.read().decode())
data2 = json.dumps(data)

print(data2)
```

`json.dumps()` function converts a Python object into a json string.